# How to send an alert and also refresh the page?

Tags: asp.net

I've been reading some topics from `StackOverFlow` and I found some ways to refresh the page like:
 `Response.Redirect(Request.RawURL);, Response.Redirect(Absolute.Uri) etc...`

But I need to send an alert of confirmation and ALSO refreshes the page... Now, I'm using this method to send the alert:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", "alert('Well Done !');", true);
```

But using any of these methods to refreshes the page, the alert isn't fired. So I need to know a method that is a good practice to do this.
Because I have some `DropDownList` with data from `database` and I'm making some `Edits` on the data, so when the user clicks on the button to `edit` the current data, it shows up a message like `edit successfully` then refreshes the page with the new data.

Comment: To refresh you can use document.location.reload(true);

Comment: @ShariqueAnsari And what about the alert? Will be fired aswell?

Comment: you can use this alert('Well Done !');document.location.reload(true);

Comment: @ShariqueAnsari What is the differente of your `document.location.reload(true)` and `window.location.reload` ? And why is the `true`parameter? Thanks Sharique

Comment: If you add the boolean true to the reload window.location.reload(true) it will load from server

Comment: Got it ! and is there a huge difference between `document....` and `window...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about client redirect?

```
alert("You're now will be redirected");
window.location.reload();
```

Since alert() is synchronous function, redirect will fire only when user click "ok"

Comment: I never used this. Where do I use these codes? And I want all of this to be fired when the client clicks on the button `edit`. But not in the exactly momment the user press the buttom. I want the alert/refresh to be fired, when all the methods has been successfully done.

Comment: Register this script via ScriptManager as in your question is fine I guess. Your sample does not call alert() because page reloads before any scripts executed.

Comment: OMG, WORKED !! Thaanks man :D Is there something bad about using this method? Or it IS a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

The above client script can be added in your codebehind this way.

```
protected void Render()
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder stringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder("<script "
        + "type='text/javascript'>"
        );
    stringBuilder.Append("alert('hi');");
    stringBuilder.Append("window.location.reload();");
    stringBuilder.Append("</script>");

}
```