# How to send a message on the screen and redirect to a different page

Tags: asp.net

Sometime ago, I asked about "how to send an alert and reload the page" and I found the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15616006/1919644)
But now I need to send this alert/ message of confirmation like `New Registration Successfully done` AND redirect to a different page.
And I have no idea how... The way I used to do, will only reload the currently page, and if I make a `Response.Redirect("PageName.aspx");` it will NOT show the alert.
What could I do?

**UPDATE**
Now, I found this `window.location.href = 'pagina.aspx';` But I don't know if it is a good practice or how to use this, on codebehind, this method does not exists...

Comment: So this would be a client side alert, followed by a page redirect in the code behind?

Comment: @MikeSchwartz Exactly !

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092640/how-to-redirect-a-user-to-a-new-webpage-after-a-javascript-alert-confrim-box

Comment: @DavidePiras I do not have the method `window...` Do am I missing a namespace` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to load script from code behind.

### Page without Ajax

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Do something 
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "redirect script", 
   "alert('New registration successfully done!'); location.href='pagina.aspx';", 
   true);
}
```

### Page with Ajax

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Do something
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "redirect script", 
   "alert('New registration successfully done!'); location.href='pagina.aspx';", 
   true);
}
```

Comment: What is the diference between them ? performance maybe?  
Obs: The first one didn't worked, but the second one worked PERFECT. Thanks !